# Haskell Type Problem with the ":" operator

Tags: haskell

I have to learn Haskell and one exercise was to say If a piece of Code would Work for the Compiler.
The ":" works as a -> [a] -> [a] with a some variable type

My Problem is now the following:

```
1. []:[[[1]],[]]
```

And

```
2. [[],[1]]:[[]]
```

The Probleme is that GHCI gives out:

```
1. [[],[[1]],[]]
```

And

```
2.[[[],[1]],[]]
```

Now that doesn't make any Sense to me ,because i combine Lists which dies Not cotaim Just one Kind of Element Like in 1. or in combine two Lists with the Same Type while i need in the Front of ":" a non list Item Like I wrote down in the top of this Question, so why does this Work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-empty brackets are just syntactic sugar for chains of `(:)`.

There are two ways to create a list. To create an empty list, you use `[]`. To create a list from an existing list of objects `y` and another value `x` of the same type as the elements of `y`, you use `x:y`.

So any other use of brackets can be desugared to a combination of empty brackets and `(:)`. Some simple examples:

- `[a] == a:[]`
- `[a,b] == a:b:[]`
- `[a,b,c] == a:b:c:[]`

In each of the above cases, if `a, b, c :: t`, then `[] : [t]`.

In your case, you have lists *of* lists, so it starts getting a little confusing, because no matter how "nested" the type gets, `[]` still the empty list. So with #1, `[]:[[[1]],[]]`, you have:

- `[]`: the empty list of type `Num a => [[a]]`
- `[[[1]],[]]`: a list that desugars to `[[1]]:[]:[]`, consisting of two lists of type `Num a => [[a]]`, namely `[[1]]` and `[]`.

The result of the expression, then, is in fact `[[],[[1]],[]]` or `[]:[[1]]:[]:[]`.

One other confusing point: in the completely desugared expression `[]:[[1]]:[]:[]`, the first two occurrences of `[]` have type `Num a => [[a]]`, just like `[[1]]`. The *third* one, though, being the right-hand operand of the last `(:)` constructor, has type `Num a => [[[a]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps type hints will help illustrate what's going on.

For problem 1:

```hs
([] :: [[Integer]])
  :
  [ ([[1]] :: [[Integer]])
  , ([] :: [[Integer]])
  ]
```

For problem 2:

```hs
([ ([] :: [Integer])
 , ([1] :: [Integer])
 ] :: [[Integer]]
)
 :
 ([[]] :: [[[Integer]]])
```

You should be able to paste each of those examples into a REPL to see that they work.

An empty List is of type `forall a. [a]` where `a` can be anything, including `[[Integer]]`, which is why these examples work.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks for the correction. I've edited my answer. I've been working with PureScript more than Haskell recently and messed up the PS -> Haskell translation of the examples I ran in a PS REPL.

Comment: No problem (PureScript looks nice and is something I'm intending to look into, but haven't got round to yet - I've already played with Elm for front-end development, and like it, but PS seems much nicer, and closer to Haskell).